# how to know is signature of all versions is same or not?

Tags: android, debugging, signature

Here is explain what happened: first I published my app(v1.0) in cafebazzar.ir store (my country's store). we works with debug version there. then I start to work for v1.1 but I corrupt app. so I deleted my project' directory and pasted it from Backup. then I make new version of my app and published it. but I don't know the signatures of versions is same or not?
sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompress your APK and get the file META-INF/CERT.RSA, than use keytool (you can find it inside bin directory of your JDK):

```
keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA
```

It returns the fingerprint of the certificate used to sign the APK

```
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 10c06dd0
Valid from: Sat Oct 04 13:38:57 CEST 2014 until: Mon Sep 26 13:38:57 CEST 2044
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  5B:6A:E3:89:16:48:DF:57:47:19:45:11:67:36:DC:E1
         SHA1: 7A:DC:81:60:44:F2:36:9A:C6:74:1E:CF:61:F2:FA:12:0E:23:E8:36
         SHA256: 5E:24:E8:A9:BE:C5:DD:A2:25:82:7C:A3:F1:50:DC:C1:0C:DF:F6:88:EB:9B:A5:08:F7:B3:97:64:EF:5E:6F:4F
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3
```

Comment: in this example "6324" is signature? or all of "sm" line? (there is a "s" line too) I think signatures is different. so what can I do to change signature? or do something...

Comment: I just updated the answer with a better method to retrieve the exact fingerprint. Please take a look

Comment: keytool with the command princert reads the certificate from the file specified, and prints its contents in a human-readable format. This is all the info included in the certificate

Comment: any simple new projects signature is same to my app signature. why?

Comment: Have you used the release keystore and the release private key to sign the apk generated from the new project? Please check here for more information http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Every project have the same signatures for this reason, the certificate used is the same, the signature is also the same.